# How do I style a tag within an ID using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to style the li elements within the "eventsList" ID in this HTML file using Javascript. I've been playing around with the code and for whatever reason, the styling isn't working. I feel like this must be a super easy solution, but being a newbie, I can't get it figured out. 
The first four bullet points should be styled in bold and with an orange font color, if it were working.

```js
function findElements() {
  var events = getElementById('eventsList');
  var linkItems = events.getElementsByTagName('li');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < linkItems.length; ++i) {
    linkItems[i].style.color = 'orange';
    linkItems[i].style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  }
}

window.onload = findElements;
```

```html
<h2>Subheading</h2>
<ul id="eventsList">
  <li>List 1</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li><a href="www.google.com">Linked list Item</a></li>
  <li>List 4</li>
</ul>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Method is `document.getElementById()`, not ...`getElementById()`. Open browser dev tools console (F12) and look at error thrown

Comment: [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) doesn’t exist in the global scope - you have to call it on `document`. This should be apparent from the error printed to the console when your function is executed

Comment: Just curious why no CSS to do this?

Comment: @James If I had it my way, I'd definitely be using CSS! I'm taking a Javascript course and I'm required to experiment with styling in Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use `document.getElementById` :

```js
function findElements() {
  var events = document.getElementById('eventsList');
  var linkItems = events.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (var i=0; i< linkItems.length;++i) {
    linkItems[i].style.color="orange";
    linkItems[i].style.fontWeight="bold";
  }
}
window.onload = findElements;
```

```html
  <ul id="eventsList">
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 2</li>
    <li><a href="www.google.com">Linked list Item</a></li>
    <li>List 4</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Wow, I knew it had to be something so simple! Thank you, I can't believe I was missing that.

Answer (score 1):

You've got one little problem. `getElementById` doesn't exist on it's own. It is a property of `document`. The corrected line looks like this:

```
var events = document.getElementById('eventsList');
```

For future problems, here's how you can discover the issue for yourself. Open your developer tools (F12 in many browsers) and look in the console. You'll see an error saying that `getElementById` is not defined. That's a reminder to make sure you're referencing the right method and on the right object.

Answer (score 1):

You're really close! Just some basic errors. You need to execute the function at the bottom and you need to get eventsList from the document.

```
function findElements() {
  var events = window.document.getElementById('eventsList');
  var linkItems = events.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (var i=0; i< linkItems.length;++i) {
    linkItems[i].style.color="orange";
    linkItems[i].style.fontWeight="bold";
  }
}
window.onload = findElements();
```